# unittest jsut runs 1 out of 4 test cases

Tags: python, python-unittest

We have this assigment where i should run these four test cases with the help of unittest but when I run it with the command python test.py (name of the file) it just says it ran 1 test what am I doing wrong?

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
def numpy_determinant(arr):
    if len(sp.Matrix(arr).rref()[1]) < max(np.shape(arr)):
        return 0
    else:
        return np.linalg.det(arr)

def scipy_determinant(arr):
    return linalg.det(arr)

class ArrValue:
    value = np.array([[2, 1],
                      [2, 2]])

class TestMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_positive(self):
        # test case 1
        arr1 = ArrValue()
        arr_det_np = numpy_determinant(arr1.value)
        arr2 = ArrValue()
        arr_det_sc = scipy_determinant(arr2.value)

        # Test case 2
        arr1 = ArrValue()
        arr_det_np = numpy_determinant(arr1.value)
        arr2 = np.array([[2, 1, 0],
                         [2, 2, 0]])
        arr_det_sc = scipy_determinant(arr2)

        # test case 3
        arr1 = ArrValue()
        arr_det_np = numpy_determinant(arr1.value)
        arr2 = np.linalg.inv(arr1)
        arr_det_sc = scipy_determinant(arr2.value)

        # test case 4
        arr1 = ArrValue()
        arr_det_np = numpy_determinant(arr1.value)
        arr2 = np.linalg.transpose(arr1)
        arr_det_sc = scipy_determinant(arr2.value)

        #test case 5
        arr1 = ([[1,0,0],
                 [0,0,0],
                 [0,0,1]])
        arr_det_np = numpy_determinant(arr1)
        arr2 = ArrValue()
        arr_det_sc = scipy_determinant(arr2.value)
```

Comment: You only have 1 test there that does 5 things

Comment: For `unittest`, you need `n` methods which each assert once to get a report about `n` tests being run.

Comment: so I need to do 4 diffrent classes with 1 test case in each?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can do that, but with closely related tests, each can be a different method named test_*

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing wrong? - Expecting incorrect outcome from test runner.
You have only 1 test.
Tests are defined with methods, not comments. Check unittest documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html
The test runner counts the number of tests by

> def test_

methods in the class.
You can divide one large test into several smaller ones:

```
class TestMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_positive_1(self):
        arr1 = ArrValue()
        arr_det_np = numpy_determinant(arr1.value)
        arr2 = ArrValue()
        arr_det_sc = scipy_determinant(arr2.value)

    def test_positive_2(self):
        arr1 = ArrValue()
        arr_det_np = numpy_determinant(arr1.value)
        arr2 = np.array([[2, 1, 0],
                         [2, 2, 0]])
        arr_det_sc = scipy_determinant(arr2)

    def test_positive_3(self):
        arr1 = ArrValue()
        arr_det_np = numpy_determinant(arr1.value)
        arr2 = np.linalg.inv(arr1)
        arr_det_sc = scipy_determinant(arr2.value)
```